# Why enable_if_t needs to have datatype identifier and a default value?

Tags: c++, c++17, enable-if

I am unable to understand how the 2 commented code lines in below snippet are different than the lines just ahead of them? Is there an easy way to understand the meaning of the commented lines vs the meaning of lines just ahead of them? I am unable to speak in my mind as how to read the commented line and the line next to it. Could anyone please explain? And don't point me to the documentation please. I have spent time there and still its not clear to me else i wouldn't be posting this question here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

//template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool>>
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> K = true>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Integral version";
}

//template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>>
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> K = true>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Floating point version";
}

int main()
{    
    fun(4);
    fun(4.4);
}
```

following errors are shown when i use commented code and i dont know what they mean or how the above code resolves them.

```
Error(s):
2044199993/source.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
2044199993/source.cpp:22:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(int)’
     fun(4);
          ^
2044199993/source.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_integral_v<T>, bool>::type <anonymous> > void fun(T)
 void fun(T value)
      ^~~
2044199993/source.cpp:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
2044199993/source.cpp:22:10: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
     fun(4);
          ^
2044199993/source.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>::type <anonymous> > void fun(T)
 void fun(T value)
      ^~~
2044199993/source.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
2044199993/source.cpp:22:10: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
     fun(4);
          ^
2044199993/source.cpp:23:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(double)’
     fun(4.4);
            ^
2044199993/source.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_integral_v<T>, bool>::type <anonymous> > void fun(T)
 void fun(T value)
      ^~~
2044199993/source.cpp:8:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
2044199993/source.cpp:23:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
     fun(4.4);
            ^
2044199993/source.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: template<class T, typename std::enable_if<is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>::type <anonymous> > void fun(T)
 void fun(T value)
      ^~~
2044199993/source.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
2044199993/source.cpp:23:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
     fun(4.4);
            ^
```

Comment: did you try the lines you want to write and read the compiler error message? It already tells a lot

Comment: Ask yourself:  What value should the `bool` object that is the result of `std::enable_if_t<cond, bool> K` be if you do not give it one?

Comment: @NathanOliver more correctly, what is they *type* of `K` if `cond` is false?

Comment: @NathanOliver : can i get away without using bool and a default value? is there any option eg. void or null?

Comment: @Caleth nope, the type doesnt really matter, neither in the `false` nor in the `true` case, though when the condition is `true` it needs some value from somewhere

Comment: @Helena There are, but I find the method of using `std::enable_if_t<condition, bool> = true` works the best.  If you can upgrade to using C++20, you can start using [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) which makes writing similar code a lot less verbose.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I would happily upgrade to c++20 but i think i am not very comfortable with c++14/17 yet so want to get hold of concepts there first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following in itself is completely fine:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool>>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Integral version";
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Floating point version";
}
```

Its templates with two template arguments. The issue arises when you want to call them. If you try to call them like you do in `main`:

```
int main()
{    
    fun(4);
    fun(4.4);
}
```

You will get an error along the line of:

```
<source>:18:5: error: no matching function for call to 'fun'
    fun(4);
    ^~~
<source>:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void fun(T value)
     ^
<source>:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void fun(T value)
     ^
<source>:19:5: error: no matching function for call to 'fun'
    fun(4.4);
    ^~~
<source>:5:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void fun(T value)
     ^
<source>:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
void fun(T value)
     ^
```

The templates have 2 template arguments. One is `T` the other is either a `bool` or a substitution failure. The second argument cannot be deduced from the function parameters, hence the error.

Consider what you get in case of `T==int`. `std::enable_if_t` is just an alias. In your case either for `bool` or the alias is not defined:

```
template<int, bool>  // because int is integral
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Integral version";
}

template<int, "substitution failure"> // because int is integral
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Floating point version";
}
```

The second is a substitution failure, so overload resolution picks the first. And it has two template arguments.

The second template argument is not used for anything but to fail when the condition is `false`. You do not want the user to call

```
 fun<int,true>(42);
```

You want the caller to call it via

```
 fun(42);
```

because explicitly specifying the tempalte argument would defeat the whole purpose of SFINAE here. The way to not reqiure the caller to specify the template argument in case it cannot be deduced is to supply a default. And thats the `K = true`. `K = false` would work as well. And as you do not have to name the argument the following works as well:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool> = true>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Integral version";
}

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true>
void fun(T value)
{
    std::cout << "\n In Floating point version";
}
```

Comment: you said `The second argument cannot be deduced from the function parameters, hence the error.`. Why so? Isn't the value 4 telling that its integral and 4.4 saying its float?

Comment: when the condition to `std::enable_if` is true then its `type` (or `_t`) is `bool`, ie in that case you have `template <class T, bool>` or `template<class T,bool K = true>`

Comment: @Helena templates stuff is sometimes hard to grasp, because it wasnt initially designed to work like this. Most of this just worked "by coincidence" and C++20 makes things much simpler. When you write `template<class T,....>` then inside `<>` its only a list of template arguments, you cant simply put a condition there. Here SFINAE works by resolving either to `template <class T,bool K = true>` or to `template <class T, ---not a type, because enable_if_t<false> does not exist--->`

Comment: So fun(4) with `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, bool>>` resolves to `template <class T, bool>` and hence error? Alternatively, when i use `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::integral_v<T>, bool> K = true>`  then does it resolves to `template <class T, bool K=true>`  so no error? Is `template <class T, bool=true>` is no error as well when i don't use `K`? Do you see where i am confused? I am trying to see how the code is valid or invalid after enable_t conidtion check.

Comment: @Helena see edit.

Comment: "Is template <class T, bool=true> is no error as well when i don't use K?" thats already in the answer. There is no need to name the argument, because it isnt used